# Spring Cloud Vault Profile Specific Bootstrap

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I have a Spring Boot Application and I would like to Load configurations from Vault based on the Profile I am running. At present i have 2 profiles (dev, prod). My Dev Profile uses a H2 database where as the Prod Profile uses a Posgres DB. Running the dev Profile loads the correct config from Vault but running with the Prod Profile seems to be skipping it somehow and not looking in Vault.

**bootstrap.yaml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  profiles:
    active:
  cloud:
    vault:
      host: localhost
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      uri: http://localhost:8200
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        default-context: my-app/dev
      fail-fast: false
```

**bootstrap-prod.yaml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  profiles:
    active: prod
  cloud:
    vault:
      host: localhost
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      uri: http://localhost:8200
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        default-context: my-app/dev
      fail-fast: false
```

For example running the command `gradle` will load configuration from vault. But running `gradle -Pprod` fails to load the correct configuration from Vault.

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax to activate your profile when using gradle:

```
./gradlew clean bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=prod'
```